# Save HTML table to readonly file/document

Tags: javascript, android, html, file, pdf

I am trying very hard to convert a HTML table into a readonly document with exactly the same display. It can be PDF, all sorts of image types or another type of document or file: it just can't be possible to edit this document. The conversion should happen on a user click and this is a widget for an android smartphone app (not used on browsers, its not a webpage!).

I've been trying to convert this HTML table into PDF with 'jspdf' but until now its not being possible. I'm using an online platform which allows me to use HTML and JS.

Here is a big part of my HTML:

```
<table>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#2AD2C9"><h2>Purchase Order</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#97D700"><h3>Equipamiento</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><b><em>Tipo/Cantidad</em></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Modelo de Placa:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><select id="tipoPlaca" size="1">
    <option id="defaultP" value="0">Seleccione una placa</option>
</select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Modelo de Inversor:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><select id="tipoInversor" onchange="espacioArreglos()" size="1">
    <option id="defaultI" value="0">Seleccione un inversor</option>
</select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">Longitud de PVC:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><input type="number" id="longitudPVC" onchange="calculoCableria()" size="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Cantidad de arreglos:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><input type="number" id="cantidadArreglos" onchange="espacioArreglos()" size="1"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Cantidad de placas:</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><div id="container"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#97D700"><h3>Total de equipamiento</h3>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Total de placas:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><input type="number" id="totalPlacas" readonly></td>
</tr>

 <tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Total de junctions:</td>
   <td align="center" bgcolor="D4D4D4"><div id="totalJunctions"></div></td>
</tr>
```

On the end, I want to click on the 'ConvertPDF' button and it should automatically generate a PDF that would exactly look like the table made by me:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><button type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="eliminarContenido('totalJunctions');clearArray();">Reset</button></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="ConvertPDF" onclick="something()" /></td>
</tr>
```

I tried already different approaches seen in other posts using 'jspdf' but nothing worked so far... As you can see, I'm not an experienced programmer so I would appreciate very much some help to learn how to do this! It does not need to save a pdf, just needs to save in a type of file that you can't edit!

Comment: Perhaps taking a screen shot then saving the resulting image would work? A quick google for your issue brought this to my attention https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Is this question significantly different from [this your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002631/convert-html-table-to-pdf-using-js-in-2stacks-online-platform)?

Comment: This is being used on a smartphone, not a webpage! But yes, it would work! :)

Comment: @Teemu, I just deleted that one, thank you for noticing... I'm in despair trying to find a solution for this